# Not able to set spring.datasource.type in spring boot 1.4

Tags: spring-boot

The question is  "  Not able to set spring.datasource.type   " ,

In spring boot 1.3 can work , but in spring boot 1.4 can't work , I don't know why ?

The following is  my application.properties:

```
spring.datasource.type= com.alibaba.druid.pool.DruidDataSource
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/api-2016
spring.datasource.username = root
spring.datasource.password = root
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.max-active=20
spring.datasource.max-idle=8
spring.datasource.min-idle=8
spring.datasource.initial-size=10
```

Can anyone tell me why ?

Answer (score 0):

As of Spring Boot 1.4, we no longer map the `DataSource` instance to `spring.datasource` so all the customizations (`max-active`, etc) aren't applied.

Please read [the release notes](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-1.4-Release-Notes#datasource-binding). The customizations on `DruidDataSource` were never supported and this was working as a side effect. You can restore that behaviour by creating your own datasource bean:

```
@Bean
@ConfigurationProprties("app.datasource.druid")
public DataSource dataSource() { ... }
```

And change your druid-specific settings to `app.datasource.druid`. If you enable the [annotation processor](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#configuration-metadata-annotation-processor) you'll get content assistance in your IDE for those keys!

Having said that and poking at the code, I realize now that we effectively broke `spring.datasource.type` so I've created [#6695](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/6695) to track that issue.

Comment: I konw the spring boot in 1.2 can not support, but in 1.3 support it, why cancel the support in 1.4 ?